# How to find the first commit introducing a specific tree?

Tags: git, git-fsck

Given the following `git fsck` output

```
$ git fsck --strict --no-dangling
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error in tree deadbeefabad1dea38efe0a776ce5ac0b98b3d6c: not properly sorted
Checking objects: 100% (9293/9293), done.
```

How do I find the **first commit** that introduced this bogus tree?